# Antivirus warning in kotlin-util-io-1.6.21

Tags: kotlin

I'm learning Kotlin and Spring Boot and recently am running into an antivirus warning about a file called oneeva.a!ml while building my project and gradle downloads kotlin-util-io-1.6.21.jar

`org.gradle.internal.resolve.ArtifactResolveException: Could not download kotlin-util-io-1.6.21.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-util-io:1.6.21)`

This happens when I try to build a new Spring Boot project. No one else online seems to have encountered this before. Does anyone have any guidance?

*edit: This problem occurs when creating a new spring initializer build using **Gradle** but not on Maven.*

*edit 2022-05-14: New gradle projects are working fine now without any differences in configuration*

Comment: Can't really conclude much without you saying where you got the jar from, what the checksum of it is and which anti-virus software you're talking about. The jar from mavencentral seems to not trigger anything: https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/c02c5470563218b703be1e716e2d0cea5787d35cbeb6bc946df00c00cd42acd2

Comment: I got the same issue when building a generic Kolin Coroutines project today.

Answer (score 1):

I also got the same issue after creating a new project on **Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 3** . I tried manually downloading `kotlin-util-io-1.6.21.jar` but it is getting blocked on my Windows machine due to some virus detected. Downgrading to `kotlin-util-io-1.6.20` worked for me.

Comment: I had the same issue with manually downloading the jar - whether gradle downloaded the jar or I did it manually the AV throws one of a few virus messages

Answer (score 0):

Got it resolved by updating your Windows Defender database through Windows Update.

I just updated antivirus database to the latest version, works again.

See: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-52297

Comment: The link you posted is 404, is this the right link or did jetbrains take down the issue?

Comment: Just checked it, it worked here, check your network.